# Formula field logic

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying to create a formula field that looks at two fields to determine the result in the formula field. see below my logic;

If field Status = "Ruled Out" and the field Ruled Out Reason = "Wants to sell" or "Agent" or "Fund" then the result in the formula field should read "Unacceptable". I have created the logic below but it does not work. Can anyone please help with this ??

```
IF(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL (pba__Status__c,"Ruled Out"),
        ISPICKVAL(Ruled_Out_Reason__c, ("Wants to sell property"OR"Agent"OR"fund")
    ),
    "Unacceptable",
    ""
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the straight forward option as follows:

```
IF(
  AND(
    ISPICKVAL( pba__Status__c, "Ruled Out" ),
    OR(
      ISPICKVAL( Ruled_Out_Reason__c, "Wants to sell property" ),
      ISPICKVAL( Ruled_Out_Reason__c, "Agent" ),
      ISPICKVAL( Ruled_Out_Reason__c, "fund" )
    )
  ),
  "Unacceptable",
  ""
)
```

Alternatively you could try use `CASE` as a workaround (as shown in the idea mentioned below, with its constraints)

ℹ️ You could try to up-vote this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Boz1AAC) to see if they implement something